# Distinguishing between asynchronous method callbacks in C#

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, event-handling

Let's assume I have an async method, which notifies me via an event when a certain change happens. Currently I'm able to assign the event's information to a static variable like this:

```
    static EventInfo result = null;



    // eventHandler, which assigns the event's result to a locale variable
    void OnEventInfoHandler(object sender, EventInfoArgs args)
    {
       result = args.Info;
    }



    resultReceived += OnEventInfoHandler;        

    // async method call, which fires the event on occuring changes. the parameter defines on what kind of change the event has to be fired
    ReturnOnChange("change");
```

But I would like to assign the callback value to a locale variable like this:

```
var result_1 = ReturnOnChange("change1");
var result_2 = ReturnOnChange("change2");
```

So I could distinguish between different method calls and their corresponding events, without using any static fields.

Comment: if you are assigning the result of events from asychronous activities to static members you are almost garaunteed to have a concurrencey problem.

Comment: in this case I could use a lock, but that's not the main issue I asked about :)

Comment: Where is the definition of `EventInfoArgs`?

Comment: I did not provide any definition for this, since it only contains some information on the changes, that occured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use TaskCompletionSource.

```
public Task<YourResultType> GetResultAsync(string change)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<YourResultType>();

    // resultReceived object must be differnt instance for each ReturnOnChange call
    resultReceived += (o, ea) => {
           // check error

           tcs.SetResult(ea.Info);
         };

    ReturnOnChange(change); // as you mention this is async

    return tcs.Task;

}
```

You can then use it this way:

```
var result_1 = await GetResultAsync("change1");
var result_2 = await GetResultAsync("change2");
```

If you dont want to use async/await mechanism and want to block the thread for result, you can do this:

```
var result_1 = GetResultAsync("change1").Result; //this will block thread.
var result_2 = GetResultAsync("change2").Result;
```

Comment: my mistake, the actual invocation of the async method happens on a server. So when I call my ReturnOnChangeMethod it doesn't block (but it's not tagged as async), but the actual computation is not happening on my machine

Comment: I don't expect `ReturnOnChange` to be tagged with async. I only meant it has asynchronous behavior - meaning it does not block for server to  fire the event.

Comment: when I try to use the await statement the compiler tells me, that it is only applyable for methods with an async modifier. BUT: when I ommit it, it seems to work perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

If `EventInfoArgs` is extended to include the data you require, passed from the asychrnous activity then, you won't need to distinguish. The handler implementation will know everything it needs.

If you don't want to do that, what `object` are you returning as the `sender`?

Comment: The `EventInfoArgs` inherits from `AsyncCompletedEventArgs`. Is it what you mean? 
EDIT: So I can just change the `EventHandler`'s returnvalue to EventInfo and that's it?

Comment: the sender object is an instance of the request being made when calling the method. It's being used to communicate with a server to get informed on an occuring change. I can't exactly tell, what it is doing on the serverside, since I did not implement it.